# JavaFX Offline Webpage Caching

Tags: swing, caching, webview, javafx, offline-caching

I currently have a swing Application with a WebView panel(via some javafx in swing). The WebPanel interfaces with the application itself by using 'invalid' protocols, keywords and hooks, and basically is not distinguishable from the rest of the UI.

All of that information is relevant, because on intial load, the webpage has to load, which can take a bit of time depending on server and client side variables.

What I need to do is have a way to save an offline copy of the webpage, and display it immediately on load. Since this is more critical and will not follow the rules of the actual underlying cache, I think it would be better if I manually did this instead.

Any information to help out here would be appreciated, like the best way to go about saving an offline copy of a website. I am hoping their is an easy way to achieve this without scanning the html for other references, recursing into all of these references, and reassigning the address to a local one, which seem a bit much for what I am trying to achieve.

The reason for the web based ui is because this portion of the UI is regularly updated, and gives the greatest freedom without pushing unnecessary program updates.